# Zeros and poles of $\frac{z^2}{z(z-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that the function

$f(z) = \dfrac{z^2}{z\cdot(z-1)^2}$, with $z \in \mathbb{C}$

has zeros and poles within complex analysis. My problem is to understand the simplification

$f(z) = \dfrac{z}{(z-1)^2}$ as a prerequisite to the analysis.

Why we have a zeros $= \{ 0 \} $ and poles $= \{ 1, 1 \}$ ?

and we are not considering zeros $= \{ 0, 0 \} $ and poles $= \{ 0, 1, 1 \}$

Answer (score 2):

The type of a singularity of a function $f(z)$ at $z=a$ is determined by the behaviour of the function as $z \to a$.

In this case, $0$ is a removable singularity because $f(z)$ has a finite limit as $z \to 0$.  It is also a simple zero of the function obtained by removing that singularity (which is $z/(z-1)^2$).

Answer (score 0):

The same point cannot be both a zero and a pole for a function, because we cannot have a function both go to zero and go to infinity around the same point.

It helps to give the two functions here different names: let $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z(z-1)^2}$, and let $g(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}$. If you only analyze $g$ by itself, then I think it's clear why there is a zero at $z=0$ and a double pole at $z=1$. Well, the function $f$ is simply $g$ multiplied by $\frac{z}{z}$. This fraction is equal to $1$ at every point except $z=0$, where it is undefined. Thus, $f$ is identical to $g$, except for becoming undefined at one point.

Being a pole involves approaching infinity in the neighborhood of a point, and since $g$ does not do that, then neither can $f$, which is identical to $g$ in that whole neighborhood, except for the one point.